# IE8 returns NaN

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

For some reason in Internet Explorer 8 (and probably 7) the follow section of code doesn't wok, any ideas?

```
var middlelatlong = bounds.getCenter();

//when alerted middlelatlong = (51.65494320798432,0.5499464196260533);

var x = 0;
var keys = new Array();
for(var key in middlelatlong){
    if(x <= 1){
        keys[x] = key;
    }
    x++;
}

var southlong = middlelatlong[keys[0]]-0.00017;
```

Returns `NaN` in Internet Explorer 8 but in all other browsers it equals `51.654790472326724`.

Comment: Do you actually know what `middlelatlong = (51.65494320798432,05499464196260533);` is doing? JavaScript is not Python. I don't think that other browsers return the value you said, or your actual code is different. Given your code, in every browser, `middlelatlong[keys[0]]` will be `undefined` and the subtraction will therefore result in `NaN`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Bracketing problems apart, 05499464196260533 doesn't look at all right - you might need to put back the missing decimal point...

Comment: Assuming lat long is referring to Latitude and Longitude, your longitude is not a valid longitude number.

Comment: Sorry guys the value should of read 0.5499464196260533, it was a typo.

Comment: Your code still does not make sense. `middlelatlong = (51.65494320798432,0.5499464196260533);` will assign the value `0.5499464196260533` to `middlelatlong`. Meaning, it is not an object or array. The body of the `for` loop is never executed and whatever `keys[0]` is, it is not a method of a `Number` object.

Comment: The code has this line above it: var middlelatlong = bounds.getCenter(); however middlelatlong therefore then equals (51.65494320798432,0.5499464196260533) if you alert it.

Comment: Well, that clarifies it. You should update your question accordingly. If you provide an example, then you should at least make sure that it does not introduce any new errors which conceal your actual problem. `(a,b)` is not the same as `[a,b]`.

Comment: @Felix Kling: StackOverflow should automatically demand a link to http://jsfiddle.net for all questions tagged `javascript` and containing code.  :-)

Comment: @RichieHindle: What if jsFiddle is down? That seems to happen quite often, unfortunately. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are tying to achieve with your code, but I assume that `middlelatlong[keys[0]]` returns something which is not a number.

It seems that you are using the Google Maps API and that you want to access the latitude part of the coordinates. You should read the [document](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) properly and use the API to access the information instead of your own try to extract the information.

If `getCenter` refers to [the method described here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map), then it returns a [`LatLng`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) object. You can access the latitude with `lat()` then (or if you want the longitude, use `lng()`):

```
var southlong = bounds.getCenter().lat() - 0.00017;
```

---

Your problem is that you are making assumptions about the order in which the properties of an object are traversed, but this order is not defined, this is implementation dependent. So you cannot say that the first two properties will be the coordinates, the object has other properties as well, which might be traversed first in IE.

Comment: Ok guys I have sussed it out. Internet explorer orders the keys within middlelatlong in a different order so using keys[0] and keys[1] only worked if the array was in the correct order.

Comment: @ElliotReeve: Are you using Goggle Maps API or not? If you do, then use the provided methods.

Comment: Nice find re bounds.getCenter().lat(), solves all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

On the first line I think you mean:

```
middlelatlong = [51.65494320798432,0.5499464196260533];
```

Also, in your for loop, just use regular iteration and incrementation.

Comment: How do you mean? Do you have an example?

Comment: Also note `0...` is an octal number.

Comment: `for (x=0; x<something ;x++)`. What are you trying to do with this code chunk?